# searching multiple elements in different django models using haystack search

Tags: django, django-haystack

Any help on how to search multiple elements input in Django separated by comma. I have two fields of the same names in all my models.
I got this ajax.js code:

```
$(function(){

        $('#search').keyup(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/predictgene/search/",
                data: {
                    'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                },
                success: searchSuccess,
                dataType: 'html'
            });

        });
    });

    function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        $('#search-results').html(data);
    }
```

My search index. I have about 25 search indexes, I just need to be able to search multiple input text separated with a comma or space. The results should show the name of the models and all the elements search for. 
    my search_index.py

```
 class ArthrogryposisIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
     text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
     gene = indexes.CharField(model_attr='gene')
     #  prediction = indexes.CharField(model_attr='prediction')
     # pub_date=indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')

     content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='gene')

     def get_model(self):
         return Arthrogryposis


     def index_queryset(self, using=None):
         """used when the entire index for model is updated."""
         return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Comment: can you show the `view` connected to the `/predictgene/search/` service?

Comment: I only want to search multiple inputs from different  models. I'm using haystacks search for this. I wasn't using views... is it possible to perform a string search of several entries separated by comma or space. for instance in a search_box I input : book1, book2,... and search for these items in two or more models.

Comment: that javascript calls the `/predictgene/search` service, you need that service inside Django for your project to work.

Comment: Hell eLRuLL thanks for your reply. What is the best way to search strings in haystack or django.